# How to continuously vibrate phone in both android and IOS using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, vibration

I am using **vibration: ^1.7.5** package in which we have to specify the time in milliseconds.

I am now using this to vibrate the device till 10 minutes
`Vibration.vibrate(duration: 600000, amplitude: 255);`

but is there any way by which we can keep vibrating the device continuously until
we want?

Comment: You are setting the duration to whatever you want . What do you mean continuously until we want ??

Comment: I mean don't stop vibrating until, I say to stop programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use repeat with a pattern like below which will continue the vibration until cancelled.

```
Vibration.vibrate(pattern: [100, 200, 400], repeat: 1)
```

Link to the source
[Github Link](https://github.com/benjamindean/flutter_vibration/blob/ff72cede4ca1ded770a66685168f73c7cee05523/vibration/test/vibration_test.dart#L55)

Comment: i cant get this code to work for ios 16, i get the following error:[hapi]  CHHapticPatternPlayer.mm:132   -[PatternPlayer initWithPlayable:engine:privileged:error:]: ERROR: pattern contains no playable events
Failed to play pattern: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.).